# Using Boolean difference and a cube in cutting a plane

Tags: modifiers

Due to (possibly) a misjudgement in using Archimesh to create a number of rooms in a house, given that the non-solid topology is pretty unfriendly if you want to work on the rooms created, I have created an outer wall, using extruded edges from a plane, to allow me to use materials on the outside of the house.

This meant I would now need to cut the appropriate holes for windows and doors in this outer wall. It seemed that creating a cube of the correct dimensions, intersecting with the wall and using Boolean difference, would allow the hole to be created. This is not the case and given my actions, I believe I do understand why. The wall simply added the cube shape to my wall. I expect at the point of intersection within this, there will be a hidden hole as I guess difference does mean that the solid vertices of the cube also count in the difference.

I saw someone used Rotation & Scale on the cube, before applying boolean difference, and clicking on the plane but this did not seem to work for me. Can I use the cube method or is there another way to do this accurately?

I have attached screenshots of one of my attempts.

[image: Created cube]

[image: Cube intersecting with plane and new modifier]

[image: Result of Boolean modifier]

Comment: I'm struggling to follow exactly what you're trying to do. Am I correct in assuming you just want to cut holes out of your wall via booleans? If you don't mind, please post the process you are following and at what step the problem occurs.

Comment: if you want to cut holes for windows or doors it will much faster and better in terms of topology to not use booleans but create edge loops and delete faces...

Comment: Pane is outer walls of a house and at points, I need to cut the window shape. I have create a cube with same dimensions as window and is in the same x/z geometry as the hole I required in my pane. This means I can simply pull the cube along the y axis to intersect with the pane. I have viewed many videos where using the boolean difference between 2 solids creates a hole once the hole shaped solid is deleted. Many examples show cylindrical holes created in solids. I try this but am left with the cube shape now attached to the pane after the initial cube is moved away. Not sure about edge loops.

Comment: Sorry about the misspelling of plane above....The issue was that the plane did not interact the same as two 3d objects, as in all the examples I have seen. I unioned the cube to the plane, and this changed it into a cube object. I could then delete faces of the extra cube and after that, all boolean differences for other windows worked perfectly and created the correct holes.